# Tensorflow Python: Cannot Restore variables using tf.train.Saver(): Error::Not found: Key Variable/Adam not found in checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am confused. I don't know what's happening. I cannot restore my checkpoints. The weird thing is sometimes I can restore them then after 1-2 hours I can't.

I use this code to save

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    .....
    #sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, 'models/my_model_2.ckpt')
```

I use this code to restore

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, 'models/my_model_2.ckpt')
    ......
```

Error

```
2020-10-15 01:10:35.195112: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at 
save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Not found: Key Variable/Adam not found in checkpoint
```

If you don't know how to fix this, just tell me if there is another way to restore variables.
Also, my program is a CNN with neural network at the end. Im using tensor flow for everything.

Answer (score -1):

change your optimizer from Adam to other?
i don't know why,but i solve this problem by this way.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, I would like to know your solution and possible reasons.Please tell me.